# Django South Migration does not work the first time around

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm running a South migration `python manage.py syncdb; python manage.py migrate --all` which breaks when run on a fresh database. However, if you run it *twice*, it goes through fine! On the first try, I get

```
DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'model': 'mymodel', 'app_label': 'myapp'}
```

After failure, I go into the database `select * from django_content_type` but sure enough it has

```
13 | my model     | myapp      | mymodel
```

Then I run the migration `python manage.py syncdb; python manage.py migrate --all` and it works!

So how did I manage to make a migration that only works the second time around? By the way **this is a data migration** which puts the proper groups into the admin app. The following method within the migration is breaking it:

```
@staticmethod
def create_admin_group(orm, model_name, group_name):
    model_type = orm['contenttypes.ContentType'].objects.get(app_label='myapp', model=model_name.lower())
    permissions = orm['auth.Permission'].objects.filter(content_type=model_type)
    group = orm['auth.Group']()
    group.name = group_name
    group.save()
    group.permissions = permissions
    group.save()
```

(The migration files come from an existing working project which means a long time ago I had already run schemamigration --initial. I'm merely trying to replicate the database schema and initial data onto a new database.)

Comment: I've had a couple of these and I believe it is because when it first tries to run the migration the model hasn;t been created yet and creates it after that bit fails. The next time because the model is there it runs fine

Comment: So is this considered a bug in South? I expect that the migrations will be run in order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in South.

http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1281

Answer (score 1):

Of course its going to be like this, you have not made any intial schemamigrations. The right way would be like this:

1. Register your django apps with `south` first. So something like: 
   `python manage.py schemamigration --initial <app_name>`.
2. Then you run `manage.py syncdb`.
3. After this, you run `migrate` like so `python manage.py migrate <apps>`, please note that simply running `migrate` will just migrate all your registered apps. I tend to do this.
4. If you change models to change the schema, then you can simply use: 
    `manage.py schemamigration --auto`

The problem that you are alluding to is this. Once you run `syncdb`, you already get a table crated, south had nothing to do with this. What you are hence doing is querying a database that has no migration control (iirc).

Comment: I tried to do what you said but it didn't work. At step 2 it failed with: DatabaseError: relation "south_migrationhistory" does not exist.

Comment: I realize now that I might not have provided enough information. I had already run schemamigration --initial. I'm merely trying to deploy a working migration history onto a new server.

Comment: @Mark: My bad, do step 3 before step 2.

Comment: Well in that case I had been running the commands in that order and I'm still getting the failure.

Comment: @Mark: Well, I'll be making a screencast on this soon. So, I will update this when I can. Check this out in the mean time: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to issue `python manage.py syncdb; python manage.py migrate --all` for the first time. First of all, I won't trust much in `--all` option. It may include Django's oficial libraries and you certainly don't want that, even when *There's nothing to migrate* in them. I rather go by `python manage.py migrate <app_name1> <app_name2> ...`

But for what South concerns, the way of using South is:

1. Create an app
2. Create a migration for it with `python manage.py schemamigration --initial <app>`
3. Convert to south and exising migration with `python manage.py convert_to_south <app> --auto`
4. Do some modifications to the app and then `python manage.py migrate <app>`

Your approach might actually work, but take into account that when you do `migrate --all` you don't controll the order of migrations applied, and `python manage.py syncdb` won't assure the `contentType` your accessing is (myapp, mymodel) available at that time.

The error is appearing only first time because maybe the migration is actually being applied once. And getting save in the `south_migrationhistory` table as already applied, so when you issue the command again, it ignores it.

My advice, migrate first the target apps, after the `syncdb` command. If this doesn't work or things get messy, try this:

1. Comment the line `'south',` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Issue `python manage.py syncdb`
3. Remove comment from line `#'south',` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
4. Issue the final command `python manage.py migrate --all`

Good luck, hope this helps!

Comment: The reason that the migration failed was not because of the --all flag, nor was it because of a mistake in the south_migrationhistory table. It was because South has a bug and does not deal with the contenttypes table correctly.

Comment: @Mark: Great discover, so sad it made you thought my answer deserved a downvote.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I think it will help people who are creating their first migrations but it was not the correct answer for my question and I didn't want people to be misled. Sorry!